# What are the preferred Android apps for gaming?

Tags: tools

What Android apps do you use for gaming? 
 What are the preferred dice rollers, time keepers, audio/video recorders, notes, etc.?

- Please present only one App per answer so that they may be rated and sorted automatically by user votes.
- Also, please indicate whether the apps you list are intended for only phones, only tablets, or optimized for any display size.

I have been experimenting with two programs so far, and I will enter them below so that others who have used them can rate them accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

We've actually had lots of success with Dropbox - it's relatively easy for people to share character sheets, material, notes, etc. with each other (or the GM) using shared folders, and you can pull the files up on whatever phone/tablet/etc. you'd like.  It also means the GM has access to the latest version of everyone's character sheet, and there's versioning available.

Have the GM create one shared folder for everyone, then one shared folder per player that is just for the GM and that individual player.  If nobody's using Dropbox, have the GM invite everyone (to get the 250MB boost from inviting people).

Comment: Great suggestion!

Answer (score 9):

[Quick Dice Roller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ohm.quickdice) allow to customize your dice and support almost all game system.

Each dice can be a single roll (d6), a multiple roll (3d6) or any complex roll (3d6+(1d7/2)).

Special functions can be used to emulate complex systems (like dice pool, exploding dice, roll&keep) and the built-in [dice builder](http://ohmnibus.blogspot.it/2012/04/expression-builder.html) make the creation process very easy.

It support many other features like on-the-fly modifiers, clipboard, roll linking, roll quality indicator and more.

Interface is designed to be easy and fast to use, and support all screen sizes.

Answer (score 6):

[Dice bag](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-droidhut-dicebag-xxiA.aspx) looks useful especially since it can generate rolls in advance thus speeding up combat.

Comment: It's back on the market and it's very neat.  You can premake a bunch of rolls, so like, "Fireball Damage: 3d6+3"  Click it and keep going.

Answer (score 2):

[Diceshaker D&D](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pallosalama.dice.dnd&feature=search_result) is by far the best dice app if you like 3D dice.  It doesn't allow you to enter modifier numbers, but you can roll any mixture of dice together and it has 4 virtual dice trays where you can keep a different set of dice in each one so you don't have to select a different group of dice each time you want to make a roll.  It works on most tablets as well.  The physics are excellent as well and allow for some adjustment.

The only drawback is price.  When I bought it, it was only a buck or two.  Now the price has been jacked up over 4 bucks.  But even at that price it's cheaper than the last set of dice you bought.

Comment: just download the free version with just a 3d6, I was skeptical and planning on be bored... I'm floor how nice it is.

Answer (score 1):

[RPG Sidekick](http://www.zapadroid.com/droid/id/87607/com.sunfire.rpgsidekick), provides fully customizable rolls, keeps a time stamped log of results, and allows for specific dice combinations to be saved. It does not involve graphical representations of dice.

This application resizes appropriately for a 7 or 10 inch tablet.

Answer (score 1):

[Sync Voice Note](http://www.zapadroid.com/droid/id/175391/com.wujie.svn) caught my eye as a way to mix and match my end of session recaps with my note-taking to speed up and clarify both processes. I can record my thoughts about my notes, or the players's comments, while making sure to put the key points down clearly in writing for fast scanning.

This application works smoothly both on phones and on 10 inch tablets.

Comment: Link appears to be down; store link is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wujie.svn&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

web browser + link to rules.

Quick access to any rules needing a look up.

Answer (score 1):

I use [DnD Buddy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidytools.dnd.buddy) as a character sheet - it includes dicerolling and automatic greying out of encounter / dailies as you use them. Absolutely love it.

Answer (score 1):

I find that I use [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) more than any other app when gaming. Spreadsheets for character sheets, Docs for notes, quick links, and session recaps, Draw for mapping, and I also keep a library of quick-reference files. Accessible from my phone, tablet, and laptop with equal ease. Especially for D&D3.X, being able to share Spreadsheets with other players makes it much easier to help them build/tweak their characters.